# VSTO send email from custom Form button in Outlook

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2019

My goal, the user wants to send a new email, after filling in (`.TO`, `.CC`, `.Body` etc) and clicking on the send button will display a custome `Form` where the sending options are. One option is to send the email as the user created it (normal `send` button function).
Is there any idea how to assign `ItemSend` function to button in custom form ?

`ThisAddIn.cs` -> open custom Form

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.ItemSend += new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(Application_ItemSend);

    }
```

`Application_ItemSend`

```
   private void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
   {
        if (Item is Outlook.MailItem)
        {
            Form1 f = new Form1();
            f.Show();
        }

        Cancel = true;
    }
```

`ChooseFormSend.cs` -> custom sending button,

```
    public void btn_standard_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
         //mail.Send() -> send email which user whant to send        

    }
```

UPDATE (all aswers to gether, to make this work)

`ThisAddIn.cs`

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.ItemSend += new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(Application_ItemSend);

    private bool ProcessEmail(Outlook.MailItem mailItem, MailSendType SendType)
    {
        switch (SendType)
        {
            case MailSendType.Normal:
                return false;

            case MailSendType.WithAdverts:
                //mailItem.BCC += "ad@server.xyz";
                mailItem.HTMLBody += @"<b>Some bold text at the end :)</b>";
                mailItem.HTMLBody += @"1233";
                return false; // send the mail

            case MailSendType.WithCoupon:
                mailItem.CC += "coupon@server.xyz";
                mailItem.HTMLBody += @"";
                return false; // send the mail

            // by default don't send the mail
            default:
                return true;
        }
    }

    private void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        if (Item is MailItem) // ensures Item is a mail item
        {
            using (Form1 form_ChooseForm = new Form1())
            {
                DialogResult dr = form_ChooseForm.ShowDialog();
                if (dr == DialogResult.OK) // shows the form as a dialog
                {
                    Cancel = ProcessEmail((MailItem)Item, form_ChooseForm.SendType);
                    // MessageBox.Show("The OK button on the form was clicked.");                 
                }
                else
                {
                    // MessageBox.Show("Cancel process");
                    Cancel = true;
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

`ChooseFormSend.cs`

```
using Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace OutlookControll

{
    public enum MailSendType
    {
        NoSend,
        Normal,
        WithAdverts,
        WithCoupon
    }
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public MailSendType SendType = MailSendType.NoSend;

    private void Btn_ShowSecondForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddItemsForm f2 = new AddItemsForm();
        f2.ShowDialog();
        this.Hide();
    }

    private void Btn_cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button Btn_cancel_Click = new Button();
        Btn_cancel_Click.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
        this.Hide();
    }

    public void Btn_standard_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button Btn_standard_Click = new Button();
        Btn_standard_Click.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        Controls.Add(Btn_standard_Click);
        SendType = MailSendType.Normal;
        this.Hide();
    }
```

}

`Btn_standard_Click.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK` can be setup in `Properties` -> `Behavior` -> `DialogResult` -> OK, Cancel, Abort, etc.

Comment: Why can't you use MailItem.Send? Since Application_ItemSend will fire again, you can set a custom property to skip that email. Or you can display your forma modally and confine all processing to the Application_ItemSend handler.

Comment: @dmitry streblechenko so add to button application_itemSend ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean - button lives on a form, not in an event handler.

Comment: ok, so where to put part of the code application_itemsend for button of form?

Comment: In your form. Clicking your button would close your form and let Application_ItemSend  continue to execute. If you want to cancel the submission, set the cancel parameter to true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 potential scenarios I can consider:

1. Press send > Form pops up > Select option on Form > **Modify email contents** > Send email
2. Press send > Form pops up > Select option on Form > **Create and send new email (sending 1 or more new emails)(discard old email)** > Send email
3. Press send > Form pops up > Select option on Form > **Create and send new email (sending 1 or more new emails)(send old email)** > Send email

Note that once modifying the email contents can mean modifying everything. Change the sender change the subject etc. So if you want to create a single new email and discard the old one option 1 still works to just manipulate the original email completely.

## The Dialog to allow the user to select the relevant options.

Note: When placing the form buttons ensure to set the `DialogResult` option under Behavior in the properties inspector. This allows for a `DialogResult:OK` to be returned once clicking one of the buttons automatically closing and returning from the dialog.

```
public enum MailSendType
{
    NoSend,
    Normal,
    WithAdverts,
    WithCoupon
}

public partial class SendItemForm : Form
{
    public SendItemForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public MailSendType SendType = MailSendType.NoSend;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendType = MailSendType.Normal;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendType = MailSendType.WithAdverts;
    }
}
```

## Option 1: Only modifying the contents of the email

Note the show `f.ShowDialog()` instead of `f.Show()` this stops the current thread from continuing the send operation and waits for the user to select a button on the form. The  `f.SendType` from the dialog is set and used to indicated which option the user selected. Using `ProcessEmail` the email can me manipulated and `return false` results in the manipulated email being send as the `false` propagates down to parent functions `Cancel = false` (Don't cancel the send).

```
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // create a global event listener for sending items
        Application.ItemSend += new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(Application_ItemSend);
    }

    // this function is used to modify the mail object before sending it (More variables could be added to extend the functionality)
    private bool ProcessEmail(Outlook.MailItem mailItem, MailSendType sendType)
    {
        switch (sendType)
        {
            case MailSendType.Normal:
                return false; // send the mail as is don't mainpulate the mailItem variable

            case MailSendType.WithAdverts:
                mailItem.BCC += "ad@server.xyz";
                mailItem.HTMLBody += @"<b>Some bold text at the end :)</b>";
                mailItem.HTMLBody += @"</img src='https://server.xyz/ad1.png'>";
                return false; // send the mail

            case MailSendType.WithCoupon:
                mailItem.CC += "coupon@server.xyz";
                mailItem.HTMLBody += @"</img src='https://server.xyz/coupon1.png'>";
                return false; // send the mail

            // by default don't send the mail
            default:
                return true;
        }
    }

    private void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        if (Item is Outlook.MailItem) // ensures Item is a mail item
        {
            using (SendItemForm f = new SendItemForm()) // creates the form
                if (f.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) // shows the form as a dialog
                    //if statement ensures the process will only proceed if an OK is returned 
                    //(The form has a cancel button or it could crash or anything else)
                    Cancel = ProcessEmail((Outlook.MailItem)Item, f.SendType); // process the email with the SendType
        }
    }
```

## Option 2/3 Sending new emails

This method highlights how to send new emails in outlook. Note: Tested sending email with `MailItem.Send()` and it does not call `Application_ItemSend` again

```
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.ItemSend += new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(Application_ItemSend);
    }

    private void SendNewEmail(string to, string greeting, MailSendType sendType)
    {
        Outlook.MailItem newMailItem = Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
        newMailItem.To = to;
        newMailItem.SendUsingAccount = Application.Session.Accounts[1]; // Optional can leave blank to send from default account (Array starts at 1)
        newMailItem.Subject = "New Mail";
        newMailItem.Body = $"{greeting} {newMailItem.To}\nExample Body from {sendType.ToString()}";

        // Part of Original answer but it's not relevant. However I will leave it in the event that it is of use to someone
        //((Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)newMailItem).Send += (ref bool Cancel) => { /*do nothing*/ };

        newMailItem.Send(); // send the mail
    }

    private void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        if (Item is Outlook.MailItem) // ensures Item is a mail item
        {
            using (SendItemForm f = new SendItemForm()) // creates the form
                if (f.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) // shows the form as a dialog
                {
                    //if statement ensures the process will only proceed if an OK is returned 
                    //(The form has a cancel button or it could crash or anything else)

                    // send 3 mails
                    SendNewEmail("admin1@server.xyz", "Hi", f.SendType);
                    SendNewEmail("admin2@server.xyz", "Hello", MailSendType.Normal);
                    SendNewEmail("admin3@server.xyz", "Yo", f.SendType);

                    // either send or don't send the orginal one
                    // by default Cancel is set to false (So by default the message will send)

                    // send the 3 mails and send the original one typed up by the user
                    //Cancel = false;

                    // send the 3 mails and do not send the original one currently typed up by the user
                   // Cancel = true;
                }

        }
    }
```

Between these 2 examples and the `f.ShowDialog()` setup you should be able to find the solution you seek. You can also mix and match by modifying the original email and sending additional one.

Comment: what im doing wrong, i follow your option 1, and email will be send only when i click cancel botton, or close form with cross button in right up corner in form.

Comment: In the method `void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)` the `Cancel` variable can be set.
`Cancel = true; // Message will not send`
`Cancel = false; // (Default) Message will send`
`ShowDialog()` will return `DialogResult.OK` or `DialogResult.Cancel`. From this you can set `Cancel`
See the [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult) example and
see this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846573/using-dialogresult-correctly) for a bit more detail on how the a modal dialog works.

Comment: Updated question about all information collected. Let's make it a little more complicated, what if I have a second ````Form```` ? To send another type of email? ````Application_ItemSend```` controls the first form. One of the buttons of the first form opens the second form where the user is prompted to enter ````Imput```` and the email is sent to the same recipient as in the case of the first form

Comment: The new updated question while valid is not entirely related to the first question. You are better off asking a new question. Large problems can be broken down into smaller targeted ones. Focused question are better suited to SO. Searching "multiform c# application" turns up many results. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462592/best-practices-for-multi-form-applications-to-show-and-hide-forms) SO link shows some slightly more complex approaches to handling a multiform setup. I would also suggest using a wizard style approach (click next and back rather opening new forms)